# Как правильно построить предложение

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите, пожалуйста, перестроить предложение:

> Наступает весенне-летний период, который каждый человек в любом
>   возрасте ждет с большой радостью и надеждой на предстоящий отдых,
>   планирует проведение отдыха на природе в выходные и праздничные дни, а
>   также проведение определенных работ на своих приусадебных участках,
>   дачах, в домиках.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Наступает весенне-летний период, который каждый человек в любом возрасте ждет с большой радостью и надеждой на предстоящий отдых.  Пора планировать отдых на природе в выходные и праздничные дни, а также проведение определенных работ на своих приусадебных участках и  дачах.

2.Наступает весенне-летний период, которому каждый из нас рад: предстоит отдых на природе в выходные и праздничные дни, а также приближаются весенние хлопоты на  приусадебных участках , дачах и в домиках.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня что-то никак фантазия не работает.